# Starting an activity and passing uri data

Tags: android, image, android-activity, uri

In my onActivityResult I have two if statements one is getting a picture from the gallery and the other is getting a picture from the camera. After I get picture uri it starts adobe creative sdk to edit the image. After i get the edited image I want to start and pass the edited image to another activity.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        //Gets the gallery image uri
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            editPic(selectedImage);
        }

        //gets Camera pic taken uri
        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Image captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent
                Uri mpicTaken = data.getData();
                editPic(mpicTaken);
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // User cancelled the image capture
            } else {
                // Image capture failed, advise user
            }
        }
        //edited image
        Uri editedImageUri = data.getData();

        /*
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.ayyogames.photoapp.Share");
            intent.putExtra("imageUri", editedImageUri);
            startActivity(intent);
            */
    }

    public void editPic(Uri uri) {
        Intent intent = new AdobeImageIntent.Builder(this)
                .setData(uri)
                .withOutputSize(MegaPixels.Mp10)
                .withOutputQuality(100)
                .build();

        startActivityForResult(intent, IMG_CODE_EDIT);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the Uri as String like

```
intent.putExtra("imageUri", editedImageUri.toString());
```

Then in new activity, just convert it back

```
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(extras.getString("imageUri"));
```

Comment: I want start the activity and pass this data but it goes straight to the activity and not let me edit the pick first

Comment: In your onActivityResult, if you want start another activity after edit picture, you need to check requestCode : if (requestCode == IMG_CODE_EDIT) { start another activity here}

Comment: @S12 alternatively you can use intent.setData()